# Program: Words after "G"/"g" (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, task, edx

I have recently started to learn python as I wanna enter a deep learning field in future.
As I'm completely new and only started I apologize in advance if my question is silly.
I am currently doing a course on edx by name introduction to python fundamentals and as I final project of module 1 I need to make a program that asks for user input and give an output of all words that starts from h to z.

task

[image]

here is my code:

```
user_input = input("enter a 1 sentence quote, non-alpha separate words: ")
new_name = ""
for letter in user_input:
    if letter.isalpha() == True:
        new_name += letter.upper()
    elif letter.isalpha() == False:
        if new_name[0] > "g":
            print(new_name)
            new_name = ""
        else:
            new_name = "\n"
print(new_name)
```

INPUT = Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart
OUTPUT = WHERESOEVERYOUGOGOWITHALLYOURHEART

By my understanding of code I have wrote: 
- user enters input
- code check for each character 
- if letter is alpha that letter is added into new_name variable
- when encounter first no alpha character in these case space after word Wheresoever code moves to elif since after checking a fist one it was not True and elif turn to mach criteria
- then by using nested if statement  it checks if new_name variable[index0] (Wheresoever) is grater then g. 
- if it is grater it prints new_name and makes new_name empty and repeat the circle until there is no more characters to check.
- if its not greater then g it starts with new word on the new line

Now as I sad I'm completely new so I have just described my thoughts process of the code and please tell me where am I wrong and how can I corrected and improve my thoughts process and the code mentioned above.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You don't need to compare boolean values to make decisions. Intead of `if foo == True:` say `if foo:`. Instead of `if foo == False:` say `if not foo:`.

Comment: You want your output to be this ? "WHERESOEVERYOUGOGOWITHALLYOURHEART" ? Or this ?  "Wheresoever
you
with
your
heart "

Comment: @AdrianW I made these change and it has shortened my code and I learn something new, but still didn't make my code give the desired output

Comment: @VineethSai "Wheresoever you with your heart " all upper characters and each word in new line

Comment: @tkala Edited mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below, iterate trough the list split of the `user_input` string, then check if it starts with a `G` or `g`, if it does, don't keep it, otherwise keep it, then use regular expressions (`re`) to get only letters.

Also as you said you need `isalpha` so then:

```
user_input = input("enter a 1 sentence quote, non-alpha separate words: ")
print('\n'.join([''.join(x for x in i if x.isalpha()).upper() for i in user_input.split() if not i.lower().startswith('g')]))
```

Example output:

```
enter a 1 sentence quote, non-alpha separate words: Wheresoever you go, go with your heart
WHERESOEVER
YOU
WITH
YOUR
HEART
```

#### Update form @KillPinguin:

do:

```
user_input = input("enter a 1 sentence quote, non-alpha separate words: ")
print('\n'.join([''.join(x for x in i if x.isalpha()).upper() for i in user_input.split() if ord(i[0])>ord('g')]))
```

Comment: @tkala Edited mine

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply, It is not allowed for me to use import and I must solve the task only by using these: NOTE: This program requires print output and using code syntax used in module 1 (Accessing String Characters with index
Accessing sub-strings with index slicing
Iterating through Characters of a String
More String Methods[.len(), .count(), . find() ])such as keywords for/in (iteration), input, if, else, .isalpha() method, .lower() or .upper() method

Comment: @tkala Edited mine

Comment: new_name1 = '\n'.join([''.join(x for x in i if x.isalpha()) for i in user_input.split() if not i.lower().startswith('g')])
print(new_name1.upper())

I creted new variable with syntex you provied and printed with mehtod to call all upper.

thank you :))

Comment: @tkala Happy that i helped,

Comment: Why do you use `if not ... startswith('g')` ? This would imo also give you words starting with `a-f`, which you did not mention in your problem statement.
If you really require words starting with `h-z` only, then you should use `if ord(i[0]) > ord('g')`

Comment: @KillPinguin Done!